# Backend doesn't work after uploading registration.php

Tags: magento2, error, theme, component

I want to build my first theme for Magento but get stuck at the setup. I made a directory in the `app -> design -> frontend -> called myfirsttheme` and in this folder I made one called myfirsttheme.

Here I created the files **theme.xml**:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>MyFirstTheme</title>
<parent>Magento/Luma</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/theme-image.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
```

**composer.json** :

```
 {
  "name": "myfirsttheme/myfirsttheme",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "myfirsttheme/myfirsttheme": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-theme",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

and **registration.php**

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/myfirsttheme/myfirsttheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

When I open the backend I get the message:

> **There has been an error processing your request**
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 98616252

After removing the registration.php the message is gone and I can login.
But I can't install the theme. What's going wrong?

Comment: What's the error in 98616252 ?

Comment: check ... `<theme>` tag not closed in your xml

Comment: got to `var/report/98616252` and add error message too..

Comment: How about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in registration.php you need to write something like this.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'YourPackageName_YourModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

And then check. I think this is mistake you done.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you're missing the preview image. Try to add this file: `app/design/frontend/myfirsttheme/myfirsttheme/media/theme-image.jpg`.